# Confused about title of a state and concurrency representation in state machine diagram

Tags: state, uml, diagram, state-machine, statechart

[image]

My object can be at different states at time according to its variables.
So, I decided to put these possible states into a global composite state with concurrency notation.
The object can only be at one of the each couple of states shown above -at the same time-.
So, it can never be at any state other than that global state.
How should I title it?
Or should there has been some other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is another solution. The statemachine itself can have multiple regions. So, there is no need to define a global state. The UML specification clearly allows this:

> 14.2.4.3 Region
>
> A composite State or StateMachine with Regions is shown by tiling the graph Region of the State/StateMachine using
> dashed lines to divide it into Regions.

Unfortunately, the tools I know don't support more than one region in a statemachine. As a workaround I would give the superfluous global state the same name as the statemachine.